# Is there any way to give name to testNG test

Tags: java, testng

I have several unit test cases written in Java using TestNG framework. I want to specify the test case ID along with each test case. Is there any way to give name to each testNG test, something like,

```
@Test(name="TestCase1")
public void firstTestCase(){

  }
```

so that I can identify particular test method in any package using the name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading the [JavaDoc](http://www.testng.org/javadocs/index.html) you will find that [`org.testng.annotations.Test`](http://www.testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/annotations/Test.html) has a property [`testName`](http://www.testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/annotations/Test.html#testName--).

Answer (score 0):

Your test class can implement [ITest](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/ITest.html).

Or, as @lutz-horn said, you can use `@Test(testName="...")`.